# Javascript - specify all other indexed elements in array (other than the one that is called)

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I'm trying to achieve, is to somehow group together all of the indexed values in an array, other than the one  called. To clarify, I've written the following code.

The first `document.write` works as expected and prints the indexed string which correlates with the pressed button. With the second `document.write`, I'd like to print all other indexed elements except the one that has been clicked/selected. How do I group together all of the other indexed elements? Needless to say for all of you Javascript guru's, the `myarray[!clicked])` attempt in the code doesn't work.

```
<html>

<body>
<script>
var myarray = ["button1", "button2", "button3"];
function pushed(clicked) {

for (var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++) {

document.write("the button that has been pushed is" + myarray[clicked]);
document.write("the buttons that have not been pushed are" + myarray[!clicked]);
}
}
</script>

<button onclick="pushed(0)"> Button 1 </button>
<button onclick="pushed(1)"> Button 2 </button>
<button onclick="pushed(2)"> Button 3 </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print your clicked button and then your sentence about the non-clicked. Then you can use the index of the clicked one and a conditional to exclude it from the others you are printing.

```
document.write("the button that has been pushed is" + myarray[clicked]);
document.write("the buttons that have not been pushed are: ");

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    if (i !== clicked) {
        document.write(myarray[i]);       
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, nothing happens when I click the button using this for some reason.

Comment: You placed this inside your `pushed(clicked)` function?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this works, at the moment I don't understand how the 2nd line prints the remaining two button info when the end of the line is blank?

Comment: It doesn't. It' prints "the buttons that have not been pushed are: ". The loop prints the actual buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate through the array and just do:

```
var clicked = myarray[clicked];
var notClicked = myarray.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== clicked;
});
document.write('clicked is ' + clicked);
document.write('not clicked are ' + notClicked);
```

Comment: The filter iterates through the array.

Comment: Yes, I meant for cycle in the original code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function pushed(clicked) {

document.write("the button that has been pushed is" + myarray[clicked]);
document.write("the buttons that have not been pushed are" + myarray.filter((elt, i) => i !== clicked).join(", "));
}
```